# Find pairs of elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of teams `($teams = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'))`. Each team will play each other and i want make a dynamic schedule in that every team play with different day, I mean there should not be a single team that play more than one match in same day.So can any one please give me an idea that how can I make this using php.

Example :-

```
$teams = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
```

Pairs would create like this :-

```
[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]

[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6]

[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]

[4,5],[4,6]

[5,6]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question title should describe your problem from the technical/programmatic view and not from the business logic view, so that users with the appropriate technical knowledge will view and may answer it. So, something like 'Find pairs of elements in an array'

Answer (score 4):

```
$teams = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$count=count($teams);

for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$count;$j++){
        echo'['.$teams[$i].' - '.$teams[$j].']';
    }
    echo'<br/>';
}
```

Main logic is to start second loop from one more that first.